# OkHttp Upgrading from 2.5 to 2.6 breaks HTTPS tests

Tags: apache-nifi, okhttp

I'm working on updating Apache NiFi's OkHttp version from 2.5 to 2.6. When doing so all of the HTTPS tests fail with this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

The tests use a wrapper around a Jetty server as the host that it connects to. The truststore and keystore are the same for the host and client. For some reason a change from 2.5 to 2.6 is causing the server to close early.

The only thing that I'm changing is the OkHttp version in maven from 2.5 to 2.6. The test class is here (implementation is in TestInvokeHttpCommon):
https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/8c2323dc8d0e107f1a99898370c7515fa9603122/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/TestInvokeHttpSSL.java

Comment: Also I run into the same issue when attempting to upgrade to 2.7

Comment: What cipher suite does it use when you're on OkHttp 2.5? We dropped `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` in 2.6 because it is obsolete.

Comment: I pass in a SSL Factory with the 29 different default Java 8 TLS Cipher suites listed in the "defaultClientCipherSuiteList" property. One of them is `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA`.


No other variable in the SSL Factory is set with any cipher suites.

Comment: Can you get it to print out the cipher suite it uses when it successfully connects? That way you can tell if it’s the change in cipher suites or something else.

Comment: I tracked the connection to line 239 of Connection.java[1]. The connection `connectionSpec` does not list `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` as a cipher. It lists 12 TLS ciphers and 1 SSL cipher. When the `sslSocket` starts the handshake, it has null for the readCipher.cipher and writeCipher.cipher. It does have TLSv1.2 as the protocol for both.



https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.6.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Connection.java#L239

Comment: Which cipher suite gets negotiated when you _successfully_ connect with OkHttp 2.5 ? If that’s `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` then we have our smoking gun. If it isn’t then we have to figure what else has changed.

Comment: Yup, I changed back to 2.5 and found `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` on line 236 in Connection.java[1] as the cipher suite for the session.

I tried upgrading to 2.6 again and looking in the same spot (sslSocket.Sess.CipherSuite on the line that starts the handshake in connection.java) and found the cipher name to be `SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL`.

[1] https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.5.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Connection.java#L236

Comment: Fix it by configuring a custom `ConnectionSpec` to use that obsolete cipher suite. See `ConnectionSpec.java` for an example.

Comment: @JesseWilson that will work and you should provide as an answer (code temporarily below in my answer) but the bigger issue here was that the keystore did not contain any valid certificates, so once the DSS cipher suite was disabled, the client and server could not agree on any valid cipher suites. Adding a valid certificate to the keystore and trusting it in the truststore will resolve this issue and allow the use of modern cipher suites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was indeed a specific cipher suite `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` being obsoleted from the new version of OkHttp. To resolve this, code can be used to provide a custom `ConnectionSpec` instance as @JesseWilson suggested.

```
ConnectionSpec.Builder obsoleteSpecBuilder = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
obsoleteSpecBuilder = obsoleteSpecBuilder.cipherSuites("TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA");
ConnectionSpec obsoleteSpec = obsoleteSpecBuilder.build();
okHttpClient.setConnectionSpecs(Arrays.asList(obsoleteSpec));
```

However, the root issue was that the keystore and truststore used by Jetty did not have any valid RSA or DSA keys (there was one DSA key but it expired 2 years ago. Apparently the date checking was not active in previous tests). Without these keys, Jetty could not offer any RSA/DSA-dependent cipher suites, and the client thus had no compatible cipher suites once the `TLS_*DSS*` cipher suites were removed.

Adding an RSA key to the keystore and truststore resolved this issue without relying on legacy cipher suites.

```
hw12203:...src/test/resources alopresto
10s @ 12:43:08 $ keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias localhost -keystore localhost-ks.jks -validity 360 -keysize 2048
Enter keystore password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  localhost
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  Apache NiFi
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  Apache
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  Santa Monica
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  CA
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  US
Is CN=localhost, OU=Apache NiFi, O=Apache, L=Santa Monica, ST=CA, C=US correct?
  [no]:  yes

Enter key password for <localhost>
    (RETURN if same as keystore password):
hw12203:...src/test/resources alopresto
23s @ 12:46:09 $ keytool -exportcert -alias localhost -file localhost.der -keystore localhost-ks.jks
Enter keystore password:
Certificate stored in file <localhost.der>
hw12203:...src/test/resources alopresto
2s @ 12:46:34 $ keytool -import -alias localhost -file localhost.der -keystore localhost-ts.jks
Enter keystore password:
Owner: CN=localhost, OU=Apache NiFi, O=Apache, L=Santa Monica, ST=CA, C=US
Issuer: CN=localhost, OU=Apache NiFi, O=Apache, L=Santa Monica, ST=CA, C=US
Serial number: 6f3e5921
Valid from: Tue Jan 05 12:46:04 PST 2016 until: Fri Dec 30 12:46:04 PST 2016
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  9F:CE:78:6D:18:0B:CF:7D:57:50:02:10:BA:98:27:62
     SHA1: FA:70:D1:5C:BE:90:D3:CA:A0:3D:5E:67:62:D1:25:F6:31:2E:59:31
     SHA256: A8:09:89:7C:19:6E:05:5B:CB:04:09:2C:30:5B:35:85:23:0F:C6:8A:12:00:4C:9F:39:5E:40:43:86:3E:FB:09
     Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: AB 88 BA FA F7 F5 AE 22   69 E4 B6 89 3D FB B0 61  ......."i...=..a
0010: 30 95 A3 27                                        0..'
]
]

Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```